# "Depp wants to clear his name and receive punitive damages."

Tags: tense

This is from [*The Washington Post* article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/arts-entertainment/2022/04/10/johnny-depp-amber-heard-case/#O47DR7OJSFGTTDAPJDXIIHQFJI-1).

> The complaint says Heard wrote the op-ed with “actual malice” (the
> legal standard that public figures have to prove in defamation cases),
> claiming that Heard, “at the time of publication … knew these
> statements were false”; and that Depp wants to clear his name and
> **receive** punitive damages.

Does 'receive' here mean 'accept punitive damages willingly if there are his wrongdoings' or is it just a typo of 'received'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What this is is a compound infinitive.

> Depp wants to clear his name

and

> Depp wants to receive punitive damages.

Since both are infinitives, "receive" doesn't get inflected.

"Damages" is metonymy for "payments made in reparation of damages" and is used so widely in that meaning that it has acquired it.

Answer (score 1):

In legal terminology, "actual damages" are money (or other things of value) that person A must pay to person B to compensate B for harm done by A. "Punitive damages" are money (or whatever) that A must pay to B as additional punishment for doing harm.

If, say, A caused a car accident by reckless driving and injured B, a court may order that A pay B's medical bills. The court may add compensation for time that B must lose from work as a result of injuries, or for "pain and suffering". But if the court believes this was an accident, with no intent to do harm, someone just made a mistake, that will be it.

If A and B had an ongoing feud and the court is convinced that A deliberately ran into B with intent to cause harm, they may add "punitive damages" as punishment. (There may also be criminal charges, but that's another story.)

So if Mr Depp wants to "receive punitive damages", that means he wants a court to rule that he is the innocent victim in this case, that Heard acted with malice, and so Heard should be ordered by the court to give him money to compensate him for the harm to his reputation.

You seem to be thinking that Mr Depp would be the one paying the damages. No, the writer is saying that Heard would pay damages to Depp, not the other way around. Depp would receive the money. Note that this is what Mr Depp wants, not necessarily what will actually happen or what should happen. (I have no opinion about what would be just in this case. I haven't been following it and have no idea who did what to whom.)

Comment: Right, receive money from his ex. Right.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer.